# Find such sets such that $\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A\cap C) = \mu(B\cap C)=\frac{2}{3}$ and $\mu(A\cap B \cap C) = \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: measure-theory

Consider a probability space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, and let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be subsets of $X$. I am asked to find a specific probability space and those sets such that the properties $\mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A\cap C) = \mu(B\cap C)=\frac{2}{3}$ and $\mu(A\cap B \cap C) = \frac{1}{2}$ are satisfied. I guess to let $X=[0,1]$, $\mathcal{A}$ Borel sets of $[0,1]$ and $\mu$ be Lebesgue measure. Every time I try to find those sets, they only satisfy in some places but not all of the desired properties. I suspect that it is not possible to find such an example.

Comment: Try working in $X=[0,1]\times[0,1]$ instead of just one-dimension. A Venn diagram would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Idea: Consider a pizza , cut into $6$ slices of size $1/6$.  Consider for each $i$ the region $A_i$, the complement of slice $i$ (there are $6$ of these regions $A_i$). Then for every $i_1$, $\ldots$, $i_k$ distinct we have
$$\mu(A_{i_1}\cap\ldots \cap A_{i_k})= 1-k/6$$